# angular form how to show changed save button text?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

I use angular 1 form to show changed save button text.
The button text should be the follow:

- (disabled) save - when initial
- (enable) save - when edited or re-edit after saved
- (enable) saved - click save button

How can I use a simple method to resolve it?

[sample JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jancat/7g6u0yht/) or `the follow code`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.buttonText = 'save';
  
 $scope.save = function (myForm) {
   myForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.buttonText = 'saved';
  }             
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">

    <input type="text" ng-model="text1" name="text1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="text2" name="text2">

    <button ng-click="save(myForm)" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine">
     {{buttonText}}
    </button>
    
  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your button markup to this:

```
<button ng-click="save(myForm)" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine">
 {{myForm.$pristine?buttonText:'save'}}
</button>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CodeWarrior404/7g6u0yht/1/)

Comment: Much better solution actually, but I would still recommend creating a form viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a watch to the form model object and set the text back to 'Save'?

Asides from that you already have it with the initial value and setting to Saved when button is clicked

```
$scope.$watch("myFormData", function(){
  // text is 'Save'
}, true);
```

For the following to work, put all your form data in an object variable.

I.e.

```
myFormData = {};

myFormData.text1 = "hi"
```

So you can change the ng-model binding to a viewmodel - which is good practice anyway!